# How to use a variable on numpy mgrid input (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I am unable to use the numpy mgrid function inclusively with a variable.
For example this works:

```
grid_x, grid_y,grid_z = np.mgrid[0:10000:100j, 0:10000:200j,0:10000:100j]
```

While this fails:

```
shape=(1137,1925,332)
inputHHb=35
inputHHv=35
inputNk=190
inputxi,inputyi,inputzi = np.mgrid[0:inputShape[0]*inputHHb:inputShape[0]j,
                              0:inputShape[0]*inputHHb:inputShape[1]j,
                              0:inputNk*inputHHv:inputNkj]
```

How can I specify an inclusive range with the j operator when using a variable?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to answer your question with such sparse information, but I ll give it a try. Replace `inputShape[0]j` with `inputShape[0]*1j`:

```
inputxi, inputyi, inputzi = np.mgrid[0:inputShape[0]*inputHHb:inputShape[0]*1j,
                                     0:inputShape[0]*inputHHb:inputShape[1]*1j,
                                     0:inputNk*inputHHv:inputNk*1j]
```

Comment: Thank You that does fix it (sorry I think I must have posted at the same time as you)

Comment: You are welcome. :) Yeah, I posted it like 15 seconds before your own answer.